# How to prove this $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\int_a ^b f'(x)\cos{(nx)} \mathrm{d}x = 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

How to prove that the following is a limited function?

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\int_a ^b f'(x)\cos{(nx)} \mathrm{d}x = 0$$

I tried to use inequality to prove that this is a limited function and I got nothing.
Thanks!

Comment: What definition do you use for a limited function?

Comment: Do you mean *bounded function*?

Comment: Do you have any restriction on $f(x)$ or $f'(x)$?

Comment: Do you mean the limit as $n\to\infty$? The limit as $x\to\infty$ doesn't make any sense.

Comment: David H, yes. I'm sorry. I'm really tired today. Thanks.

Comment: In general, when computing $\int_a^bf'(x)\cos(nx)\,\mathrm{d}x$, we assume $f'\in L^1[a,b]$. Then $$\left|\frac1n\,\int_a^bf'(x)\cos(nx)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right|\le\frac1n\int_a^b|f'(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$|\cos{(nx)}|\leq 1\Rightarrow -1 \leq \cos{(nx)} \leq 1 $$

- When $f'(x) \geq 0:$ 
  $$ -f'(x) \leq f'(x) \cos{(nx)} \leq f'(x) \Rightarrow \\ -\int_a^b f'(x) \leq \int_a^b f'(x) \cos{(nx)} \leq \int_a^b f'(x) \Rightarrow \\ -(f(b)-f(a))\leq \int_a^b f'(x) \cos{(nx)} \leq (f(b)-f(a) ) \Rightarrow \\ -(f(b)-f(a)) \frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n} \int_a^b f'(x) \cos{(nx)} \leq (f(b)-f(a) ) \frac{1}{n} $$

Taking the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have the following:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} [-(f(b)-f(a))] \frac{1}{n} \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{n} \int_a^b f'(x) \cos{(nx)} \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  (f(b)-f(a) ) \frac{1}{n} \Rightarrow \\ 0 \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{n} \int_a^b f'(x) \cos{(nx)} \leq 0 \Rightarrow \\ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{n} \int_a^b f'(x) \cos{(nx)}=0$$

- When $f'(x) < 0:$ 
  $$ f'(x) \leq f'(x) \cos{(nx)} \leq -f'(x) \Rightarrow \\
   \int_a^b f'(x) \leq \int_a^b f'(x) \cos{(nx)} \leq - \int_a^b f'(x) \Rightarrow \\ (f(b)-f(a))\leq \int_a^b f'(x) \cos{(nx)} \leq -(f(b)-f(a) ) \Rightarrow \\ (f(b)-f(a)) \frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n} \int_a^b f'(x) \cos{(nx)} \leq -(f(b)-f(a) ) \frac{1}{n} $$

Taking the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have the following:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (f(b)-f(a)) \frac{1}{n} \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{n} \int_a^b f'(x) \cos{(nx)} \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  [-(f(b)-f(a) ) ] \frac{1}{n} \Rightarrow \\ 0 \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{n} \int_a^b f'(x) \cos{(nx)} \leq 0 \Rightarrow \\ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{n} \int_a^b f'(x) \cos{(nx)}=0$$

Comment: This proof only works when $f$ is non-deceasing. In particular, the inequality $-f'(x) \le f'(x)\cos(nx) \le f'(x)$ fails at those $x$ where $f'(x) < 0$.

Comment: Your inequalities would imply that if $f(a)=f(b)$, then $\int_a^bf'(x)\cos(nx)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$, which is not true.

Comment: I edited my answer..

Comment: $f'(x)$ can change sign over $[a,b]$, so this proof still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Using integration by parts we have
$$\frac{1}{n} \int_a^b f'(x) \cos (nx) \mathrm{d}x=\frac{\cos (nx)}{n} f(x) \bigg]_{x=a}^{x=b}+\int_a^b f(x) \sin(nx) \mathrm{d}x. $$
You may finish off using the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma).